# How do I test if a string exists in a Genshi stream?

Tags: python, stream, genshi

I'm working on a plugin for Trac and am inserting some javascript into the rendered HTML by manipulating the Genshi stream.

I need to test if a javascript function is already in the HTML and if it is then overwrite it with a new version, if it isn't then add it to the HTML.

How do I perform a search to see if the function is already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!! I have solved this by first attempting to remove the function from the stream:

```
stream = stream | Transformer('.//head/script["functionName()"]').remove()
```

and then adding the updated/new version:

```
stream = stream | Transformer('.//head').append(tag.script(functionNameCode, type="text/javascript"))
```